# How to restrict the mouseArea of a QML Slider to the handle only?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I want to implement a `Slider` using QtQuick.Controls where only the `handle` is clickable and can be used to drag the `handle`. If you click the `groove`, nothing should happen, the `handle` should stay where it is. How can I restrict the `mouseArea` of the `Slider` to the `handle` only?

In the below example the `Slider` is clickable on the whole `Slider` `width` and `height`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

Window {
    id: mainItem
    width: 800
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Slider{
        id: autoSlider
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        maximumValue: 1.0
        value: 0
        updateValueWhileDragging : false

        style: SliderStyle {
            groove: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 350
                implicitHeight: 8
                color: "gray"
                radius: 8
            }
            handle: Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: control.pressed ? "white" : "lightgray"
                border.color: "gray"
                border.width: 2
                implicitWidth: 45
                implicitHeight: 45
                radius: 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about changing the `Slider.qml` template in the "..\qml\QtQuick\Controls" folder, but I couldn't really figure out what to do.

All my search efforts lead to nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think that this goes against the behaviour of sliders on all Desktop platforms, which is something to consider for usability reasons. That aside, let's try:

```
diff --git a/src/controls/Slider.qml b/src/controls/Slider.qml
index 20d1102..da6f051 100644
--- a/src/controls/Slider.qml
+++ b/src/controls/Slider.qml
@@ -258,7 +258,7 @@ Control {
         }

         onPositionChanged: {
-            if (pressed)
+            if (pressed && handleHovered)
                 updateHandlePosition(mouse, preventStealing)
```

We don't want the handle position to change when the handle wasn't hovered to begin with, because that would mean the mouse is outside the handle.

```
             var point = mouseArea.mapToItem(fakeHandle, mouse.x, mouse.y)
@@ -272,18 +272,21 @@ Control {
             if (handleHovered) {
                 var point = mouseArea.mapToItem(fakeHandle, mouse.x, mouse.y)
                 clickOffset = __horizontal ? fakeHandle.width/2 - point.x : fakeHandle.height/2 - point.y
+
+                pressX = mouse.x
+                pressY = mouse.y
+                updateHandlePosition(mouse, !Settings.hasTouchScreen)
             }
-            pressX = mouse.x
-            pressY = mouse.y
-            updateHandlePosition(mouse, !Settings.hasTouchScreen)
         }
```

Next, move the handle position update within the `if (handleHovered)` condition of the `onPressed` handle.

```
         onReleased: {
-            updateHandlePosition(mouse, Settings.hasTouchScreen)
-            // If we don't update while dragging, this is the only
-            // moment that the range is updated.
-            if (!slider.updateValueWhileDragging)
-                range.position = __horizontal ? fakeHandle.x : fakeHandle.y;
+            if (handleHovered) {
+                updateHandlePosition(mouse, Settings.hasTouchScreen)
+                // If we don't update while dragging, this is the only
+                // moment that the range is updated.
+                if (!slider.updateValueWhileDragging)
+                    range.position = __horizontal ? fakeHandle.x : fakeHandle.y;
+            }
             clickOffset = 0
             preventStealing = false
         }
```

Finally, make a similar change to the `onReleased` handler.

This will get you what you want, albeit a little rough around the edges — literally. I think the interaction is not 100%, but try it out. With a little more experimenting, you should be able to get it working perfectly.

Another hacky option is to modify `Slider.qml` to have a `MouseArea` either side of the handle, *above* the slider itself. Each of these would fill the available space on either side of the handle, effectively stealing all mouse events the groove would receive for those areas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mitch. It is not yet working as I want it, but it is the right direction. Can't work on it until next Wednesday though. Will report back then.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to get back. Thank you again for your answer!

Instead of the slider we went with a completely different means of input, so I didn't work on the problems I still had.